# Qual a origem da expressão "Hora de Burro"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, português-europeu, expressões, frases

Qual a origem da expressão "Hora de Burro"?
Ouvi há dias num debate da TV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Baseado no que encontro no [Corpus](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/hist-gen/) (nada) e nos pouquíssimo *hits* no Google, esta não é uma expressão estabelecida no português.

Como colocado no [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/o-significado-de-hora-de-burro/24363), há indícios de que em espanhol a expressão *hora del burro* denote

> as horas a meio do dia em que se sente sonolência, quando está calor.

mas que a origem é obscura e  que

> Em português europeu, julgo que a expressão é rara, para não dizer desconhecida

Em português brasileiro, há quem [afirme](https://linguajarcearense.blogspot.com/2014/05/abarcar-rodear-com-os-bracos-um-murro.html) online ser uma expressão cearense, com significado distinto:

> A HORA DO BURRO
> Quando a pessoa age sem pensar, e depois arrepende-se,  " Onde eu estava com a cabeça quando aceitei isso? " A  resposta é simples, " na hora do burro" Com o cérebro igual ao do burro.

Mas, independentemente do significado, encontro apenas usos isolados da expressão. O mais antigo deles na peça de teatro do século XVIII [Esopaida ou Vida de Esopo](https://www.infopedia.pt/apoio/artigos/$esopaida) do autor luso-brasileiro António José da Silva ([e-print](http://www.bdteatro.ufu.br/bitstream/123456789/362/1/TT00448.pdf), pg. 10):

> Xanto. Maldito de todos os diabos, agora estás mudo? Dize-lhe alguma cousa, com que se desenfade e se alegre.
> Esopo. Suponha vossa mercê que se me secou a prosa e que estou na hora do burro.

E o mais recente numa [matéria](https://observador.pt/2023/03/02/empresario-madeirense-diz-que-acusacoes-de-ex-secretario-regional-foram-feitas-numa-hora-de-burro/) deste ano (2023):

> Empresário madeirense diz que acusações de ex-secretário regional foram feitas numa "hora de burro" [...] "Há tanta tontice naquela entrevista", disse Avelino Farinha.

Esses poucos exemplos me parecem mais casos de expressão individual que do uso de uma frase conhecida.

Comment: Fun fact: in Spanish _caerse del burro_ seems related to your last two definitions https://dle.rae.es/burro?m=form recognising one has made a mistake. Apologies for not commenting in pt but my written pt is almost non-existent.

Comment: Nunca ouvi essa expressão.